# Python code for longest common prefix string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in python. I want to write a python code to find the longest common prefix string among an array of strings. The common leading characters in all elements of the string is returned to output.

Here is a toy example. If the input is as follows:

```
strings = ["redlight", "realworld", "reason"]
```

The output would be:

```
["re"]
```

If the input is as follows:

```
strings = ["apple", "orange", "reason"]
```

The output would be:

```
[""]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a reference to future answerers: is the behavior intended to be like this, or can a prefix include the whole phrase? `[strings[0][:i] for i,v in enumerate(strings[0])if all(j[:i]==strings[0][:i] for j in strings)][-1]`

Comment: Also Matt, stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.